# Log tags in Red

Tags: android

I'm trying to delete an item from Arraylist that populates a Listview. I am unable to delete the item but when I log to see if my delete function is even being called the logcat prints in red. It logs but for some reason it's in red.

04-30 19:22:30.381    1605-1605/com.example.michaelbain.asrx E/FromListActivity﹕ REMOVE CALLED
04-30 19:22:30.381    1605-1605/com.example.michaelbain.asrx E/FromListActivity﹕ MATCH
04-30 19:22:30.391    1605-1605/com.example.michaelbain.asrx E/FromListActivity﹕ REFRESHED

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: That would be an `ERROR` log. Also visible by the `E/`

Comment: I just don't know where to look to try and fix the error since it doesn't show the related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the type of Log that you are using. Some types like error and warning are colored.

[image]

Source: [Android Developer Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

To be more specific, you can print a log in red with the ERROR one and blue with the WARN.

Also, if you are looking for a specific type, Android Studio gives you the possibility to filter your logcat output based on type:

[image]

Comment: Thank You, I'm using Log.d. Sorry to waste your time I'm using Log.e which I've never used before so the red was unfamiliar.